# Can't convert 'int' object to str

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code that causes the below error.

```
elif args[0]=="online":
    onlines = zxLoLBoT.get_friends_online(self)
    self.message(sender, "Toplam "+len(onlines)+" kişi açık.")
```

[image: error ss]

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.message(sender, "Toplam " + str(len(onlines))+ " kişi açık.")
```

You were trying to concatenate a string with an integer.

The built-in function [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) will always return an **integer type**, so you must **convert it** to a string with [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) when concatenating it another string.

```
len(...)
    len(object)

    Return the number of items of a sequence or collection.
```

Comment: oooow yis :D :D im using len(str(onlines)) XD thx for help ^^

Answer (score 4):

I would use [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to do it:

```
self.message(sender, "Toplam {} kişi açık.".format(len(onlines)))
```

This way you do not need to use extra code to convert int to str.